# How do you paste list of items in R

Tags: r

How do you paste list of items and get the result as shown below?

```
 mylist<- list(c("PDLIM5", "CBG"), c("PDLIM5", "GTA"), "DDX60")
```

result

```
PDLIM5:CBG  PDLIM5:GTA  DDX60
```

Comment: `paste(paste(mylist[[1]],collapse=":"),paste(mylist[[2]],collapse=":"),paste(mylist[[3]],collapse=":"),collapse=" ")`

Comment: @Maju116 It has variable number of items so can't use number 1..3

Answer (score 13):

you can try:

```
sapply(mylist, paste, collapse=":")
#[1] "PDLIM5:CBG" "PDLIM5:GTA" "DDX60"
```

The result is a vector.

If you want to further paste the result, you can do:

```
paste(sapply(mylist, paste, collapse=":"), collapse=" ")
#[1] "PDLIM5:CBG PDLIM5:GTA DDX60"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , exactly what I need.

Comment: @MAPK, great :-) I wasn't sure if you needed a vector as a result or just one string

Comment: Additionally, I have some items with NA's such as (c("PDLIM5", "NA"), How do I get rid of "NA" and keep only PDLIM5?

Comment: @MAPK `sapply(mylist, function(x) {paste(x[!is.na(x)], collapse=":")})` should work, or `sapply(mylist, function(x) {paste(na.omit(x), collapse=":")})`

Comment: Sorry that NA is string "NA".

Comment: @MAPK, then just use the first option and `x[x!="NA"]` instead of `x[!is.na(x)]` ;-)

Comment: @CatG Thank you, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The pipe-friendly tidyverse equivalent with a `map` function from `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)
mylist %>%
  map_chr(paste, collapse = ":")
```