# unlist strings and paste/concatenate in R

Tags: r

I have a huge dataframe with a list column`(e.g)`:

```
join_name <- structure(list(text = list(c("The", "lady", "you", "love"), 
    c("The", "dog", "you", "love"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
    class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to paste them together like:

```
join_name$text=
    [1] "The lady you love"
    [2] "The dog you love"
```

This loop do the job but is waaaay too slow :

```
for(i in 1:length(join_name$text)){
  join_name$text[i]=paste(unlist(join_name$text[i], use.names=FALSE),collapse=" ")
}
```

Any idea how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: Please use `dput` to post a [MCVE] of your data. Why can't you just use `paste0(..., collapse = ' ')`?

Comment: I think you just want `join_name$text <- sapply(join_name$text, paste, collapse=" ")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you paste list of items in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227221/how-do-you-paste-list-of-items-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks @MrFlick. Answer is:

```
join_name$text <- sapply(join_name$text, paste, collapse=" ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` way that, for a simple case, isn't really any better than base `sapply`, but for more complicated workflow might have its benefits and therefore I figured it was worth adding. It replaces `sapply` with `purrr::map_chr` and `paste` with `stringr::str_c`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(stringr)

join_name <- structure(list(text = list(c("The", "lady", "you", "love"), 
                                        c("The", "dog", "you", "love"))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), 
                       class = "data.frame")

map_chr(join_name$text, str_c, collapse = " ")
#> [1] "The lady you love" "The dog you love"
```