# Unlist a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

Having this dataframe

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("2008-07-31", "2008-08-04"), id = c(1L, 
                                                                  1L), body = list("text 2 and here another", 
                                                                                   c("another text here", 
                                                                                     "and this in the same row", 
                                                                                     "one more in the same row"
                                                                                   ))), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

How is it possible to unlist the body column to have an output like this:

> ```
>  date id                                                                  body
> 1 2008-07-31  1                                               text 2 and here another
> 2 2008-08-04  1 another text here and this in the same row one more in the same row
> ```

I tried this:

```
df$body <- as.data.frame(unlist(df$body))
```

Comment: @tmfmnk you see the print option. The first has commas. The output I try to convert is this `data.frame(date = c("2008-07-31", "2008-08-04"), id = c(1, 1), body = c("text 2 and here another", "another text here and this in the same row one more in the same row"))`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you paste list of items in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227221/how-do-you-paste-list-of-items-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `paste` in `sapply`.

```
df$body <- sapply(df$body, paste, collapse = " ")
str(df$body)
# chr [1:2] "text 2 and here another" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

With `dplyr` and `purrr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 mutate(body = map_chr(body, paste, collapse = " "))

        date id                                                                body
1 2008-07-31  1                                             text 2 and here another
2 2008-08-04  1 another text here and this in the same row one more in the same row
```