# Combining list string elements with R

Tags: r, list

I have a list containing multiple strings in each list position (see below). As you can see, in each position of the list is two string values. I want to combine both strings so that they form one string and insert a + symbol in between them.

```
print(my_list)

>> [[1]]
>> [1] "A" "B"    

>> [[2]]
>> [1] "C" "D" "E" "F"

>> [[3]]
>> [1] "G" "H"   
...
```

This would be my desired output..

```
print(my_list)

>> [[1]]
>> [1] "A + B"    

>> [[2]]
>> [1] "C + D + E + F"

>> [[3]]
>> [1] "G + H"   
...
```

So far (as a starting point) I have tried using "paste" in a for loop, like this..

```
for (i in my_list){
  print(paste(i, sep = "+"))
}
```

This did not have the intended effect. It simply duplicated each list item and did not insert a + anywhere. Here is the output..

```
print(my_list)

>> [1] "A" "B" 
>> [1] "A" "B"    

>> [2] "C" "D" "E" "F"
>> [2] "C" "D" "E" "F"

>> [3] "G" "H"  
>> [3] "G" "H"   
...
```

Any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you paste list of items in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34227221/how-do-you-paste-list-of-items-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple lapply and paste does the trick:

```r
lapply(mylist, function(x) paste(x, collapse = " + "))

# [[1]]
# [1] "A + B"
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] "C + D + E + F"
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] "G + H"
```

Sample Data:

```r
mylist <- list(c("A", "B"),
     c("C", "D", "E", "F"),
     c("G", "H"))
```